# How should I write test leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect() for a Binary search tree

Tags: java, junit

I have implemented a Binary search tree and I have written a test class (in JUNIT testing) for it. All the test except for one test goes through. The test leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect() gets a message when I debug the code.

> Expected: <4> but: was <5> . I do not know have to fix this.

Keep in mind that all the other tests goes through, and I do not think that it is a problem with the tree code.

How do you understand the description for the test?

```
/**
 * A Binary Search tree.
 */
public class Tree <T extends Comparable <T>> implements BinaryTree <T>{
    private int size;
    private Node root;
    public class Node{
        private Node Left;
        private Node Right;
        private T data;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    public Tree (){
        size = 0;
        root = null;
    }


    /**
     * Test for presence of a value.
     * @param elem
     * @return true/false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean search(T elem) {
        if(root == null ||elem == null){
        return false;
        }
        Node node = root;
        while(true){
            if(node.data.compareTo(elem) > 0){
                if(node.Right == null){
                    return false;
                } else{
                    node = node.Right;
                }
            } else if(node.data.compareTo(elem) == 0){
                break;
            } else{
                if(node.Left== null){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    node = node.Left;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Add value to tree; duplicates are not allowed.
     * Return true if the element is not already present (and is thus inserted),
     * false otherwise.
     *
     * @param elem
     * @return true/false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean insert(T elem) {
        if (elem == null){
            return false;
        }
        if (root == null){
            root = new Node(elem);
            size++;
            return true;
        }
        Node node = root;
        while (true){
            if (node.data.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
                if (node.Right == null){
                    node.Right = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Right;
                }

            } else if (node.data.compareTo(elem) == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (node.Left == null){
                    node.Left = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Left;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * The number of elements in the tree
     * @return size.
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * The height of the tree.
     * The empty tree and the tree with only the root node both have height 0.
     * @return the height of the tree.
     */
    @Override
    public int height() {
        return countHeight(root);
    }
    /**
     * Helper method for height
     */
    private int countHeight(Node node){
        if(node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + Math.max(countHeight(node.Left), countHeight(node.Right));
    }

    /**
     * The number of leaves in the tree.
     * @return the amount of leaves the tree have.
     */
    @Override
    public int leaves() {
        return countLeaves(root);
    }
    /**
     * Helper method for leaves
     */
    private int countLeaves(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return countLeaves(node.Left) + countLeaves(node.Right);
    }


    /**
     * A string describing the tree
     * @return
     */
    public String toString(){
        String str = "[" + helpToString(root);
        if (str.length() > 1) {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);
        } return str + "]";
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for toString
     */
    private String helpToString(Node node) {
        String str = "";
        if (node != null) {
            str += helpToString(node.Right);
            str += node.data + ", ";
            str += helpToString(node.Left);
        }
        return str;
      }
}
```

Test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.Timeout;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
/**
 * Test class for a tree.
 */
public class TreeTest{
    @Rule public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(5);

    Tree<Integer> tree;
    int[] elementsInTree;
    int[] elementsNotInTree;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        /**
         * This tree should look like this:
         *
         *               8
         *             /  \
         *            3   10
         *           / \    \
         *          1   6    14
         *             / \   /
         *            4   7 13
         */
        tree = new Tree<>();
        elementsInTree = new int[] {8, 10, 14, 13, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7};
        for (int elem : elementsInTree) {
            tree.insert(elem);
        }
        elementsNotInTree = new int[] {34, -3, -10, 12, 74, 5};
    }


    @Test
    public void leavesIsTwoWhenPerfectTreeHasThreeNodes() {
        // Arrange
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
        // root must be smaller than one and larger than the other child
        tree.insert(1338); // root
        tree.insert(1337); // smaller child
        tree.insert(1396); // larger child

        // Act
        int numLeaves = tree.leaves();
        // Assert
        assertThat(numLeaves, equalTo(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect() { //TEST
        // A perfect tree has all leaves at the same depth, and all internal nodes
        // (i.e. non-leaves) have two children
        //
        // This test should assert that a perfect tree with 2*n-1 nodes total,
        // has exactly n leaves (i.e. that Tree.leaves() returns n).
        //
        // An example is the perfect three-node tree from the test above:
        //
        //                        (1338)
        //                        /    \
        //                    (1337)  (1396)

        // You have to construct our own tree here, with n >= 4
        int n = 4;
        int nodes = 2*n-1;
       for(int i = 0; i < nodes ; i++) {
           tree.insert(i);
       }
         int leaves = tree.leaves();
         assertThat(leaves,equalTo(n));
    }

    @Test
    public void leavesIsOneWhenElementsWereInsertedInAscendingOrder() {
        // Arrange
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
        // insert elements in ascending order => all elements are inserted to the right
        int numElements = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            tree.insert(i);
        }

        // Act
        int numLeaves = tree.leaves();
        // Assert
        assertThat(numLeaves, equalTo(1));
    }

    // Tests for height
    @Test
    public void heightIsZeroWhenTreeIsEmpty() {
        // Arrange
        Tree<Integer> emptyTree = new Tree<>();
        // Act
        int height = emptyTree.height();
        // Assert
        assertThat(height, equalTo(0));
    }


    @Test
    public void heightIsLogOfNumLeavesTreeIsPerfect() {
        // For a perfect tree, tree.height() == log2(tree.leaves()

        // Arrange
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
        int[] elements = new int[] {8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 9, 14};
        int numLeaves = 4;
        int logNumLeaves = (int) Math.round(Math.log(numLeaves) / Math.log(2));
        for (int elem : elements) {
            tree.insert(elem);
        }

        // Act
        int height = tree.height();
        // Assert
        assertThat(height, equalTo(logNumLeaves));
    }

    // Tests for insert/height
    @Test
    public void insertValuesInAscendingOrderIncrementsHeight() {
        // When inserting elements in ascending order, each element is inserted
        // to the right of the deepest node, so the height should increment by
        // 1 for each element inserted.
        Tree <Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
        int val = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < val; i++){
            tree.insert(i);
        }
            int treeHeight = tree.height();
        treeHeight++;
            assertThat(val,equalTo(treeHeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: u should debug your test. It is important to not just lazily jump to SO but learn how to use debugger as this skill is an absolute must for any developer.

Comment: @JAsgarov I have debugged it and I got no Information that could help me with solving it

Comment: in your test that fails you are not reinitializing the tree so you are reusing the state (existing number of nodes) from the `@Before` apparently - something you would have noticed if you debugged and not just wanted someone else to do all the work for you. Sorry for the tough truth but your question shows a lack of effort. Please debug it, looks at the nodes that are in tree before each insert, and ask a specific question that you might have after you understand your test and insert methods.

Comment: @JAsgarov When I add Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>(); as first line I get:
Expected: <4>
     but: was <1> and debugging gives at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
 at TreeTest.leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect(TreeTest.java:246)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264). What do you understand about this?

Answer (score 0):

The `leaves` method counts the number of leaves that you have. Your expectation is that there will be four leaves. However, the result is 5. The method that you use in order to count the leaves appears to be correct:

```
    /**
     * Helper method for leaves
     */
    private int countLeaves(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return countLeaves(node.Left) + countLeaves(node.Right);
    }
```

It essentially counts the items (in a breadth-first-search fashion) that have no children. What could be the reason? Your main thing to find out how your tree looks alike. Based on your `insert` method:

```
    @Override
    public boolean insert(T elem) {
        if (elem == null){
            return false;
        }
        if (root == null){
            root = new Node(elem);
            size++;
            return true;
        }
        Node node = root;
        while (true){
            if (node.data.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
                if (node.Right == null){
                    node.Right = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Right;
                }

            } else if (node.data.compareTo(elem) == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (node.Left == null){
                    node.Left = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Left;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and knowing that `2*n-1` in your test is 7, so the input numbers are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, it seems to me that the tree could be

```
            0
           /
          1
         /
        2
       /
      3
     /
    4
   /
  5
 /
6
```

which would have a single leaf, because if the `node` has a greater value than the item you are about to `insert`, then you add it to the `node`'s `right`. However, the results of your test are different. For some reason you have 5 leaves. You would need to check the reason of that by first finding out how your table looks alike at the end and second by looking into the `insert` method with a debugger for this input.

Comment: Thats what I have wondered, however The code for Insert works for all of my other test. So I don't know where the problem is

Comment: @hello123 without looking at the exact tree that is generated during the test and debugging you will never find out. You need to see how your table looks alike, please look into it.

Comment: so you are saying that the problem is in the Insert method and not in the test?

Comment: @hello123 I do not know for sure. The only way to find out is to test. You have a conceptional error in the `insert`, as you insert to the `right` the smaller elements and to the `left` the greater elements, but this problem is only conceptional, meaning that you would have an inverted search tree. However, the actual culprit will only be found if you 1. Find out how the resulting tree looks alike 2. edit your question with it 3. debug your method with this input and see how that result is reached 4. edit your question and add the debug details.

Comment: @hello123 without all these the only way I could find out what your error is would be to implement your project for myself and test. But here on so we expect the askers to do the debugging and once they get debugging details/results, we are happy to help them solving the issue. There is no way to avoid the debugging. Even if here you could somehow bypass it, in the next problem it may be unavoidable. Or in the one following that. So, try learning how to debug now.

Comment: @lajor arpad I have looked and debuggd the code and dont see anything wrong. I dont see anything wrong if the insert method.

Comment: @hello123 in many cases the error is difficult to see even while debugging. My main question was: how is your table look alike when you call insert to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6?